# returning all combination of index i,j in 2d vector that sum up to desired value

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, vector, stl

I have a 2D vector `v` (all values are positive and the 2D matrix is a square matrix) and a given value `k`. For e.g.,

```
v={
   {2,1},
   {3,4}
  }

k = 3
```

I want to find and store all those combinations of `i, j` such that

```
arr[i] + arr[j] = k, or
arr[i] = k, or
arr[j] = k
```

For example `v[0][0] + v[0][1] = 3` & `v[1][0] = 3`. I want to store the pairs in an array like this `std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>>`.

```
Sample input:
v={
   {2,1},
   {3,4}
  }

k = 3

Sample output:
{{(0,0),(0,1)}, {(1,0)}}
```

Individual parts I worked by;

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
int main(){
    using namespace std;
    vector<vector<int>>v={{2,1},{3,4}};
    vector<pair<int,int>>k;
    int size=v.size();
    for(size_t i=0;i<size;i++){
        for(size_t j=0;j<size;j++){
            if(v[i][j]==3){
                k.push_back(make_pair(i,j));
            }     
        }
    }
}
```

Edit [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TxyDEBua1zbzwlTm1On5Ycnuxo4c646L/view?usp=sharing) for actual questions which I perceived and tried to solve in the above mentioned way.

Comment: why is the result a vector of maps? Ins't it a vector of pairs?

Comment: what is `cost`? Please show the real code ([mcve]) and include the error message in the question

Comment: yes sir, pairs will work better.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number ohh aplogies, cost was name of another vector, I changed the name to v, and edited the same now

Comment: in the text you write "...to store all maps(i,j) into `vector<vector<map(int,int)>>`" but thats not what the code does. Please include a [mcve] including input, output and expected output, or the compiler error message if there is one. In the code you posted, the 2d vector is empty, so thats obvisously not the code that you used for testing (also there is a `;` missing)

Comment: A simple result would be a vector of pair, so all result would go in `std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>>`.

Comment: actually sir,question i have tried to put clear all code work is mine,I thought to do it using vector<vector<map(int,int)>> but pairs will be better.

Comment: You should probably begin to solve the issue with 1D-array. (are values only positive?).

Comment: yes sir values are only positive and vector  is squared matrix

Comment: Okay, let's say the size of the given vector `v` is `n`. Then you will have n^2 elements in total. In that case, O(n^2) would be best ever complexity possible. And also if there are more such pairs than n^2 itself then your complexity would be atleast that. I just want to ask one thing haven't you considered converting this 2D array into a 1D one and then just solving the TWO SUM problem. Am I missing out something here or would that be too slow? If this is from some contest or problemset then can you maybe post the link here when we can test our solution first before posting.

Comment: Is the computation speed-critical (e.g. very large matrix)? Otherwise it seems straight-forward enough to go through the matrix with nested for loops.

Comment: @risingStark sir, this is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TxyDEBua1zbzwlTm1On5Ycnuxo4c646L/view?usp=sharing) looking for your kind help.

Comment: @Sebastian yeah it seems straight forward to traverse through nested for loop, but storing all [I,j] that sum up to desired value and using them later for our purposes seems bit complex to me. I am noob, please do help, thanks.

Comment: If the task would be speed-critical, you would sort all the elements by size (with the indices kept) to directly find matching partners instead of looking into each combination. So according to your comment the main task is to store a vector of pairs of pairs of numbers instead.

Comment: Your Google doc link is not accessible, why not paste the content here?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

The first answer I gave was considering any number of elements can be chosen to form the target sum. But since we can take only 2 atmost, here's an edit.

In case when two elements form the target sum, the gist is that when you input an element `x`, if we had already inputted `y = target - x` element in the past, pair `x` with all the occurances of `y`.

Here's the code which should be straightforward to follow.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<int, int> pii;
typedef pair<pii, pii> PIJ;

int main() {
    int N, target;
    cin >> N >> target;

    vector<vector<int>> matrix(N, vector<int>(N));
    unordered_map<int, vector<pii>> M;
    vector<PIJ> res;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
            int x;
            cin >> x;

            matrix[i][j] = x;

            int y = target - x;
            for (const pii& p: M[y])
                res.emplace_back(p, make_pair(i, j));

            M[x].emplace_back(i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Consider the problem in 1-D of length `n` first. The most naive algorithm would be to form all `2^n-1` combinations and check for each if it's elements sum up to `target`.

Luckily, the same search space can be exhausted by another algorithm which follows optimal substructure property. Let `count(i, t)` represent the total number of combinations of first `i` elements which sum up to `t`. Then `count(i, t) = count(i-1, t-arr[i]) + count(i-1, t)`. The base condition will be when `t = 0`. If `0` can be present in the input array then you will have to take that into consideration. There will be overlapping subproblems which calls for dynamic programming.

Keep a running array `chosen` and everytime you choose a value (when calling `count(i-1, t-arr[i])`), push the index into `chosen` and if you reach the base condition, push copy of `chosen` into your say `combinations` array. When the control returns back to where you called `count(i-1, t-arr[i])`, pop this value off `chosen`.

Your 2-D problem can be converted into 1-D array of `pair<int, int>` and same algorithm can be applied.

Comment: I guess the 1D problem that you mentioned is a well known subset sum problem and that is used when a subset of any size can be taken to form the sum. But here I guess that we are allowed to take atmost two values. Just a simple solution of TWO SUM problem will work to find all pairs. For individual elements just count how many elements are equal to given sum

Comment: @risingStark The question has been modified many times. When I read the question for the first time, I too thought we can take atmost 2 to form the target sum but it was not specifically mentioned so I went ahead with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The loop in your example only finds pairs `{i,j}` where `v{i,j} == k`. If you also want to include all combinations `{ {i1,j1}, {i2, j2} }` that is quite a different search.

The problem with your Sample output `{ { (0,0), (0,1) }, { (1,0) } }` is that they are different sizes. If its type is

```
std::vector < std::vector < std::pair < int, int > > >
```

then how long is the vector of pairs allowed to be? If all values of `v` were 1 would the solution then be `{ { (0,0), (0,1), (1,0) }, { (0,0), (0,1), (1,1) }, { (0,0), (1,0), (1,1) }, { (0,1), (1,0), (1,1) },  }`?

As @RisingStark comments, the most straightforward way to run this is to have an iteration over the allowed number of pairs. Which stops being trivial after 2.

Some examples for the case of 2 are [here](https://coderbyte.com/algorithm/two-sum-problem). For the subset-sum problem there is [no general efficient solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).